# Calculating Z-Score

Tags: postgresql

How do I calculate the Z-Score for a set of values in SQL (Postgresql). Calculating the z-score involves:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Window functions provide the easiest means to apply aggregated values to individual rows. Mean and standard deviation are aggregates.

```
SELECT v, (v - (AVG(v) OVER ())) / (stddev(v) OVER ()) AS z_v
FROM  (
VALUES (1),(2),(3)
) vals (v);

//-1, 0, 1
```

[Window functions documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)